# .on('change') doesn't fire for dynamic textbox input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a datepicker that is setting the value of a textbox. Every time the text in that text box changes, I want to submit the form. Here is a snippet of the code that I thought would achieve this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  watchDateFields();
}

function watchDateFields() {
  $('form .date_field').on('change', function() {
    this.form.submit();
  }
}
```

The `.date_field` input gets dynamically set, but for some reason this doesn't fire the change event?

Comment: Setting the value of an input with javascript (dynamically) does not fire the `change` event. You'll have to hook into whatever is setting the value, or try and post that code here.

Comment: @kosmos You should read the question better. They aren't creating the element dynamically, they're setting the value.

Comment: Follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667105/onchange-event-not-working-when-change-automated

Comment: I see, my fault. Too many questions of that kind. Deleting duplicate comment..

Comment: Which datepicker are you using?

Comment: Based on the answers, there must be some confusion here? Is the element added dynamically, or is it the value that is set dynamically, or more correct, programatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to attach it to a static element:

```
$(document).on('change', 'form .date_field', function() {
  this.form.submit();
}
```

Or, better replace `document` with something that is static. Eg:

```
$('form').on('change', '.date_field', function() {
  this.form.submit();
}
```

Or you might need to attach the event with the plugin's event handlers, say:

```
$('form .date_field').on('datechange', function() {
  this.form.submit();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if value is changed vis JS

Comment: @Yatix Yes, but that's not the current problem here. Plus it's almost 6 year old question.

Comment: Yes, it is, so I mentioned so I can get a working example as this one doesn't work. Do you mind sharing?

Comment: @Yatix More than happy to help. Can you create a new question and maybe add the link here in the comments? I'll be happy to look at it and provide a solution. 

Comment: All good now. It was matter of sequence rather then jQuery. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Yatix Glad it got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The `change` event will only trigger once, ie, when a user enters a new value into the input and then focuses away.

If you want this to update as a user types, use the `keydown` event.

However, submitting a form every time a key is pressed is not a good idea. What is the result you are trying to achieve? Consider at the very least validating the input or checking certain conditions are met before you submit the data (eg, make sure the input is at least 10 characters long).

Answer (score 0):

Place your `textfiels` inside a `div` element and attach the `change` event to this div:

```
$('#mydiv').on('change', '.date_field',  function(){
       this.form.submit();
});
```

Now the `mydiv` element will be watching for the change envents for all his child elements, no matter if they are dynamically generated.

Comment: Answer is not relavent

Comment: @murli2308 Why not? I offer a solution that works.

Comment: The change event will only trigger once, ie, when a user enters a new value into the input and then focuses away... This question is already there on stackoverflow

Comment: This is a wrong way of using `.on()`. Please correct it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar thank you.

Comment: Please, explain the down votes.

Comment: That looks perfect... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "input" ).keyup(function() {
  //It's changed
});
```

Easy way to track any change in anywhere... Many framework with 2 ways data binding, use keyup in Javascript to $watch the changes...

Also jQuery UI date-picker has onSelect...So easy way to do ur job... look at https://jqueryui.com/datepicker for more information...

Comment: tracking keyup is a good solution in this case!