# set value of hidden value Field Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, hidden-field

I have an asp hidden Value field:

`<asp:HiddenField Value="" ID="TitleViewerHiddenValue" OnValueChanged="TitleViewerHiddenValue_ValueChanged" />`

I have a javascript event:

```
function setHiddenValue()
{
     var x = document.getElementById('<%=TitleViewerHiddenValue.ClientID %>');
     x.textcontent = "HELLO WORLD"; // I feel this is wrong
}
```

How do I fix the javascript function so i can set the value of the hidden field and trigger the OnValueChanged event on the server?

Answer (score 0):

```
x.value
```

It's a form element, not a display element.

For triggering the change event, see [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually)

Though I think if you're doing all of this to trigger ASP's built in stuff, you're trying to build a house out of duct tape.

Comment: I realize it's kind of a hack way to do it but I just need it to work right now. I'm still not hitting my breakpoint on the server for the C# handle though, is there something that i'm missing?