# Detect the change of value of an input which loads it from a webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services

I have a simple input which loads initially its value from a webservice.

```
 <input id="inputDisponibilite" type="hidden" value="" data-match="infosBase.0.Disponibilite">
```

Here I have the attribute **data-match** which loads the value initially.

After that, I have a function which transfers the value of a slider into the value of my input.

```
slide: function (event, ui) {
       $(this).prev().attr('value',ui.value);
```

//this makes changes of the value of my input and I shouldn't touch it.

I have another function which should detect the change of value in my first input and do some treatment, but it seems that this change is not seen, maybe because I am not writing directly into my input.

I have used  :  **on('change , function () {}   / change() / and bind()** and also **eventLisneter**  of jquery, but the problem persists.

***My function :***

```
$("#inputDisponibilite").on('change',function () {

      var DisponibiliteValue = $(this).attr("value") ;
 })
```

Is there any other way to catch the change?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325938/trigger-action-on-programmatic-change-to-an-input-value

Answer (score 0):

Use `prop()`. `attr()` takes the initial value which is `""`

```
$("#inputDisponibilite").on('change',function () {
  var DisponibiliteValue = $(this).prop("value") ;
})
```

Because of the inconsistent behaviour of `attr()`, `prop()` was introduced in jquery 1.6.

However, I have no idea why aren't you using `val()` to get the value which should work properly

```
var DisponibiliteValue = $(this).val() ;
```

Comment: you have written me my same function , am using prop()

Comment: you are using `prop()`, Where?

Comment: the problem is not on that , the real problem is on the no detection of the change event on the value of input