# Trigger 'click' or 'onselectionchanging' on WinJS ListView

Tags: winjs

I a WinJS page with the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="productivity-view">
    <div class="categorylist" aria-label="Category List">
    </div>
    <div class="itemlist" aria-label="Work Item List">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to programmatically initialize two lists:

```
 var categories = new WinJS.Binding.List(list),
 categoryListEl = document.querySelector(".categorylist"),
 catList = new WinJS.UI.ListView(categoryListEl, {
     itemDataSource: categories.dataSource,
     itemTemplate: document.querySelector('.categoryitemtemplate'),
     onselectionchanging: function(event) {
         var items = event.detail.newSelection.getItems();
         items.done(function(selections) {
             var selection = selections[0],
                 item = selection.data,
                 boxes = categoryListEl.querySelectorAll('.win-itembox');

             boxes[catList.currentItem.index].classList.remove('active');
             boxes[selection.index].classList.add('active');
             workItemHeader.textContent = item.title;
             workList.itemDataSource = new WinJS.Binding.List(item.workitems).dataSource;
         });
     }
 });

 var workItemListEl = document.querySelector(".itemlist"),
 workList = new WinJS.UI.ListView(workItemListEl, {
     itemTemplate: document.querySelector('.workitemtemplate'),
     onselectionchanging: function() {}
 });
```

The code above listens for the `onselectionchanging` event on the first list, in which case the event data carries some information used to fill out the second list.

How can I programmatically trigger the `onselectionchanging` on the first item in the first list?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually)

Comment: While the question posted above may help, I'm not sure this is a duplicate. In any case, try creating an Event object and firing it, maybe update the Question if it isn't working?

Comment: I attempted all of the recommendations under @Fraser's link. They did not work for ListView.

Comment: you can try methods like add, remove etc on [listview.winControl.selection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh872204.aspx) to programmatically change the list and see whether it raises the event also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out. Solution code below. We wanted to trigger selection of the very first item in the first list, which would then put some information into the second list 'onselectchanging'. This involved listening to the 'onloadingstatechanged' event for the 'complete' state, and then adding the first item in the list to the first list's selection (the missing piece of API knowledge).

```
var catList = new WinJS.UI.ListView(categoryListEl, {
    ...
    onselectionchanging: function (event) {
        ...
    },
    onloadingstatechanged: function () {
        if (this.winControl.loadingState === "complete") {
            // try to select the first item in the list
            catList.selection.add({ key: 0, index: 0, hasFocus: true, showFocus: false });
        }
    }
});

var workItemListEl = document.querySelector("#itemListControl"),
    workList = new WinJS.UI.ListView(workItemListEl, {
    ...,
    onselectionchanging: function () {
        ....
    }
});
```