# call event from pure javascript registered by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, binding

I have a pure javascript control that does not rely on jquery which needs to raise an event. The event needs to be able to be bound and consumed by client pages that use jquery and this control. When raising the event through pure javascript, jquery does not see it. Please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/w5who6fr/

```
$(function () {
    $('#test').on('input', function () {
        alert('event triggered');
    });
});

// works
$('#test').trigger('input');

// does not work
document.getElementById('test').oninput();


<input id="test" />
```

Comment: Try document.getElementById('test').input();

Comment: what is `.oninput()`? if you created a function called that, please show that code.

Comment: document.getElementById('test').input(); does not work

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp for oninput event. But it doesn't work for any event like for example onchange

Comment: This is a built in event. Its part of HTML5 spec. It is not a custom event created by me.

Comment: Refer over here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2856602/1132354

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `oninput` is not a function of a HTMLElement.  Just use the JavaScript `EventTarget.dispatchEvent()` function.

```
$(function () {
    $('#test').on('input', function () {
        alert('event triggered');
    });
});

// works
$('#test').trigger('input');

var onInputEvent = new Event('input');
document.getElementById('test').dispatchEvent(onInputEvent);


<input id="test" />
```

I [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5who6fr/8/).

**EDIT:**

Make sure to [fire an event correctly based on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript) (thanks IE).

Comment: I see that you updated the fiddle but it still doesn't work. Run the fiddle yourself and see. Nothing gets raised.

Comment: BTW, I can't get it to work from any built in event. Try it even with the "click" event. It doesn't work.

Comment: I take it back. It works with "click". It does not work with "input" nor "change".

Comment: So no one can answer this seemingly simple question?