# How can I make content-dependent checkboxes, with a check-all box in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onchange

I have searched for hours, and tried many things, but I can't get it to work.

This is my problem: I'm trying to make some sort of summary of a book series I enjoy, in html files and I want to be able to show/hide content based on a few checkboxes at the top of a page.

So when I check only the "book 2" checkbox, no content from other books may appear.

Secondly I want a check-all button, too. For these 2 things I have 2 functions, and they do work independently, but when I click the check-all box, the content does not automatically appear, and I'm stuck to why that is.

Here's my code (HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="Scripts.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <p> <input type="checkbox" onchange="ToggleCheck(this);"> Check all</p>
    <p> <input type="checkbox" name="bookbox" onchange="ShowHide('Book0', this);"> Book 0</p>
    <p> <input type="checkbox" name="bookbox" onchange="ShowHide('Book1', this);"> Book 1</p>
    <p> <input type="checkbox" name="bookbox" onchange="ShowHide('Book2', this);"> Book 2</p>
    <p> <span class="Book0">Book 0 content. </span>
        <span class="Book1">Book 1 content. </span>
        <span class="Book2">Book 2 content. </span>
        <span class="Book1">Book 1 content. </span>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the attached JS file

```
function ToggleCheck(source) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('bookbox');
    for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
}

function ShowHide(a, b) {
    var vis = (b.checked) ? "inline" : "none";
    var book = document.getElementsByClassName(a);
    for (var i = 0; i < book.length; i++) {
        book[i].style.display = vis;
    }   
}
```

I do apologize to sign up for this site just for this, but if someone could help me, I would be very gratefull. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: Rather than `"inline" : "none"`, consider `"" : "none"` so that elements adopt their default or inherited style when visible, that way you can show and hide different types of element without knowing their display value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the `ToggleCheck(...)` function it appears that the onchange event is not triggered. You can either trigger it manually inside this method by following this: [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually)

or you can change the way you handle things a little bit and then call `ShowHide(...)` inside the for-loop in `ToggleCheck(...)`.

This edit makes it work (using the first and easiest solution):

```
function ToggleCheck(source) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('bookbox');
    for (var i = 0, n = checkboxes.length; i < n; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        checkboxes[i].onchange(); //manual trigger of the onchange event
    }
}
```