# JavaScript - UIEvent not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a function in my JavaScript file which utilises the `UIevent` interface. What it does is it will set the selected index value of a drop down box, and then fire an `onchange` event.

This function works completely fine in Google Chrome, however, in IE11, Visual Studio comes up with the error "JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action" and will not do anything.

The purpose of this function is to simulate an `onchange` WebForms `AutoPostBack` event.

JavaScript:

```
function changeForm() {
    var dropDown = document.getElementById("DDApplicationID");

    dropDown.selectedIndex = "1";
    var event = new UIEvent("change", {
        "view": window,
        "bubbles": true,
        "cancelable": true
    }); //JavaScript runtime error occurs here
    dropDown.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

WebForms

```
<!-- other html and webforms code -->
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDApplicationID" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ApplicationDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged">

<script type="text/javascript">
    changeForm();
</script>
```

As mentioned, the JavaScript code works fine with Chrome, but is throwing the runtime error on IE11. Any ideas on what is causing this issue?

Comment: Because it appears to be not supported. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent

Comment: @epascarello well, that answers my question! would you happen to know an alternative to what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually

Comment: @epascarello perfect! Thank you!