# Javascript click() not woking

Tags: javascript

I've an element in HTML, on clicking of which some processing happens. I'm trying to click that element using javascript.

First I tried

```
document.getElementById("id").click();
```

And it didn't work. Then I tried to dispatch click event like this

```
eventFire(document.getElementById("id"), 'click');

function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}
```

But this is also not working. Are any other alternatives there that I can try??

**EDIT**

Actually I've this webpage http://zzzscore.com/1to50/en/
in which there are blocks numbered from 1 to 25, and the processing happens when I click on "1".

So I'm writing a javascript function to click that automatically. The else part of the `eventFire` function is getting executed, but the processing is not happening which occurs on regular click.

Also, from chrome dev tools, I found that the blocks are registered with onmousedown event, but passing 'mousedown' as parameter to my function also doesn't work. (In case of normal mouse click, the processing still starts when I release the mouse button only)

For instance, the HTML code for block is like this

```
<div style="opacity: 1;">
    <span class="box" style="z-index:99"></span>
    1
</div>
```

And I'm passing the "div" element as parameter "el" in my function

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just define a function that runs on click, and then just call that function?

Comment: can you please explain what is not working..is the onclick handler not getting called?

Comment: Maybe this is what you looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually

Comment: added the details

Comment: You never defined an id in your html, unless were missing a piece this will never work