# Event vs CustomEvent

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I was wondering, what is the purpose of `CustomEvent`, because it can be easily emulated by good old `Event`.

So, what is the difference between:

```
var e = new Event("reload");
e.detail = {
    username: "name"
};
element.dispatchEvent(e);
```

and

```
var e = new CustomEvent("reload", {
    detail: {
        username: "name"
    }
});
inner.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Why does `CustomEvent` exist if it is easy to attach custom data to ordinary Event object?

Comment: no it is not - that answer says that `CustomEvent` is "To add more data to the event object". While this can be done with `Event` class.

Comment: I was triggered by the missing semicolon in the first example.

Comment: Did you look at [`W3C Spec`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-event)? The standards rarely explain the reasons behind decision.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It's not the same. You can't set the `detail` of a real CustomEvent:

```js
var event = new CustomEvent('myevent', {detail:123});
event.detail = 456; // Ignored in sloppy mode, throws in strict mode
console.log(event.detail); // 123

var event = new Event('myevent');
event.detail = 123; // It's not readonly
event.detail = 456;
console.log(event.detail); // 456
```

Yes, you could use `Object.defineProperty`. But I guess the point is that the argument of `CustomEvent` was supposed to set some internal data of the event. Now it only considers `detail`, which is not used internally. But a future spec could add something new, and then you may not be able to set that internal data by using properties.

A CustomEvent also inherits from `CustomElement.prototype`. That only adds `detail` and the deprecated `initCustomEvent`. But you can add your own methods or properties in there, which won't be inherited by other events. But I don't recommend this, you shouldn't modify objects you don't own.

So basically you can use `CustomEvent` in order to classify the event differently than other events. See this graphic from an [old spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20140925/#figure-event-inheritance)

[image]

Comment: But why........

Comment: Now that it’s been over 6 years, I still think that this is a really strange decision. They could’ve just redefined the `Event` constructor instead of creating a new separate pointless class that is `CustomEvent`. Or they could’ve simply encouraged users extend `Event`, just like `Error`.

Comment: @trusktr lol your comment perfectly sums up how i feel reading the bizarre justification for this class's existence