# Trying to understand the advantages of calling a function via a javascript CustomEvent over calling a function directly

Tags: javascript, custom-events

I have written a simple lightbox module which I would like to activate using a javascript `CustomEvent`.

If I were to call the function directly, I might use:

```
myButton.addEventListener('click', activateLightBox, false);

const activateLightBox = () => {

  [... ACTIVATE LIGHTBOX CODE HERE...]
}
```

But I might want to implement the lightbox in such a way that it can be activated by its own `CustomEvent`.

Let's give the `CustomEvent` the name `'lightBoxActivate'`:

```
const eventLightBoxActivate = new CustomEvent('lightBoxActivate');

document.body.addEventListener('lightBoxActivate', activateLightBox, false);

myButton.addEventListener('click', () => document.body.dispatchEvent(eventLightBoxActivate), false);
```

My conclusion is that I must be thinking about this incorrectly.

All I have achieved is that I have exchanged a button click which fires an event which launches a function for... a button click which fires an event which dispatches a custom event which then launches a function.

What is the advantage of the javascript `CustomEvent` here and how ought I be deploying it - either in this situation or in another, more sophisticated, situation?

---

**Reason for asking this question:**

When I read about the `CustomEvents API`, I imagined that it *really* enabled the developer to create a customised event - like `tripleclick` or `circularswipe` or `screenzoom` or `volumemute` etc. In the course of reading up on it, I quickly realised that it is a rather less ambitious API than I imagined. But I don't wish to discount it. So I am trying to get my head around what it *can* achieve.

Comment: Events do event things like bubbling. Not sure why you would want that here, though. Did you do this just for the sake of it instead of looking for some specific advantage?

Comment: I think this is only really useful if you use custom elements to create a React-like component-based application. Custom events could then be used to communicate between children and parents.

Comment: When I read about the `CustomEvents API`,  @Ry-, I imagined that it _really_ enabled the developer to create a customised event - like `tripleclick` or `circularswipe` or `screenzoom` or `volumemute` etc. In the course of reading up on it, I quickly realised that it is a rather less ambitious API than I imagined. But I don't wish to discount it. So I am trying to get my head around what it can achieve.

Comment: An advantage may be that an event listener can be set on multiple DOM elements such that each handles the custom event differently, as opposed to invoking a function that first has to select the set of elements and then performs something differently to each one. In this sense, it provides another way to modularize one's code. If there is only one element with an event listener, then a custom event seems to add an extra step to invoke the handler function. I'm far from an expert and perhaps ought not to comment; but I liked the question and investigated it in the past but didn't use it.

Comment: I like your thinking, @Gary, and I appreciate your contribution. It may (or it may not) be the case that because I come from a linguistic (rather than an engineering) background, once I discover and learn a new language feature, I am itching to find a context in which I can use and practice it and make it part of the "easy-access, go-to" library in my head. So far, I am concluding that `CustomEvents` relate more to program structure (eg. separation of logic / breaking things up into discrete components) than to hitherto inaccessible functionality.

Comment: Worth noting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40794580/event-vs-customevent