# How to manipulate data-binding, knockoutJs

Tags: javascript, c#, knockout.js, data-binding

I have a customer who is a member of a web site. He has to fill a form every time which is really very often. That's why he wants me to develop an application for him to make this process automatic. When I use the webBrowser control to manipulate it, I am able to login but after that there are fields that contains data-binding. These fields are the ones I need to manipulate. When I push the data to necessary fields, it's not working, because in the html tag, there is no value attribute, instead it has data-binding. So my question is how can I manipulate and push data to these fields?

Thank you so much for your all help in advance.

Comment: Did you read the documentation ? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html

Comment: yes actually, I have checked it and got the logic for data-binding. its like angularJs ng-model but the thing that i couldnt understand is manipulating it. if you have any idea on that, i would be grateful if you could share with me :)

Comment: is there any way to add a custom script into html dom?? via webBrowser control. If it is possible, maybe then could push the script into html to be able to manipulate???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout uses data-binds to listen to changes in an input and update an underlying model. For example, the `value` binding listens to `change` events and writes the new value to a data-bound `observable`.

If you update a `value` attribute through code, the `change` event isn't triggered. You'll *see* the new value in the UI, but the javascript model won't be updated.

You can combat this by explicitly triggering a change. Here's an example:

- Type in the `input`: you'll see a `console.log` that shows knockout gets updated
- Press the button to inject a new value: you won't see a log: knockout isn't updated
- Press the last button to trigger a `change` event. You'll notice knockout now updates the model.

Of course, you can combine the two click listeners into one function. I've separated them to get the point across.

```js
// Hidden knockout code:
(function() {
  var label = ko.observable("test");
  label.subscribe(console.log.bind(console));

  ko.applyBindings({ label: label });
}());

// Your code
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var input = document.querySelector("input");

buttons[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
  input.value = "generated value";
});

buttons[1].addEventListener("click", function() {
  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/2856602/3297291
  var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
  evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
  input.dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: label">

<button>inject value from outside</button>
<button>let knockout know something changed</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the share man, somehow i couldnt get the proper time to check it but as soon as possible i will try this then let you know. thanks again.