# Set the value of a form element using javascript - still prompts required field

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, knockout.js

I am setting values on a form in an iframe via Javascript. 
Please note that I do not have access to the page displayed in the iframe. My Javascript page is on the same server, so it has access to the form displayed.

```
//HTML of Forename field in form control
<input class="form-control" id="Forename" type="text" data-bind="value: dto.Forename">
```

Javascript setting the value:

```
var frameNode = document.getElementById('frm1');
var fieldNode = frameNode.contentDocument.getElementById('Forename');
fieldNode.value = FirstName; //previously defined
```

The values set successfully (see attached img). However, when I hit SAVE, I still get a 'values Required' message. I suspect this is because the [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html) Javascript libraries that binds the value with the view model, needs a keypress.

Even when I manually go into the form and press Enter/Tab after each value, I still get the message. It's only when I change the Forename and Surname manually to something else that the Save is successful.

Has anybody done something like this before? Thanks

[In this image you can see the values are set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqVXu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you're experiencing is actually due to a deeper issue involved in using a knockout binding. Updating the value of a UI control directly has no effect because the **real** underlying value is stored in a javascript view-model object. The DOM element only mirrors that value, and updates are performed using a change event hook under the hood. When you change the value manually on the UI the change event is triggered and the view-model value gets updated.

[Knockout.js Docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html)

So to properly update the values you should try using the knockout library to update the underlying data:

```
var frameNode = document.getElementById('frm1');
var fieldNode = frameNode.contentDocument.getElementById('Forename');
var viewModel = ko.dataFor(fieldNode);
viewModel.dto.Forename(FirstName); //value setting works like a function
```

If you can't get that to work you can also try manually triggering the change event. That's far easier if you have jQuery, but can still be done without. See [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually)