# Checkbox select deselect all and perform function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of checkboxes that when clicked pass their value to a text area. I then have a checkbox that when clicked selects all the other checkboxes. This is all working fine. What I would like to do is have the checkboxes perform their functions when select all is clicked. It works at the moment, but only when I refresh the page. I would like it to happen when select all is clicked.

Here's what I've been playing with so far:

```
    function setAllCheckboxes(divId, sourceCheckbox) {
    divElement = document.getElementById(divId);
    inputElements = divElement.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) 
$('.checkbox').each(function() {
                this.checked = true;
                 this.click();              
            });
{
        if (inputElements[i].type != 'checkbox')
            continue;
        inputElements[i].checked = sourceCheckbox.checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: This cannot be the actual script, because this will trigger a syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal continue statement`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually)

Comment: Sorry if this is a duplicate. I did search, but obviously missed those. This part of the code I found in a comment section on another site I was reading to find the answer. `$('.checkbox').each(function() {
                this.checked = true;
                 this.click();              
            });` I wasn't sure where it should go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using jQuery, you could do it without loops, with jQuery's [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)/[.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)/[.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/):

```js
var $result = $('.js-result');
var $checkboxes = $('.js-checkbox');
$checkboxes.on('change', function(e) {
    var $checkbox = $(e.target);
    $result.append(
        '<div>' +
        $checkbox.closest('.js-label').text() + ' is ' +
        ($checkbox.prop('checked') ? 'checked' : 'unchecked') +
        '</div>'
    );
});
$('.js-button').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $checkboxes.prop('checked', !$this.data('checked'));
    $checkboxes.trigger('change');
    $this.data('checked', !$this.data('checked'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="js-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="js-checkbox"/>
    Checkbox 1
</label>
<label class="js-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="js-checkbox"/>
    Checkbox 2
</label>
<label class="js-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="js-checkbox"/>
    Checkbox 3
</label>
<button type="button" class="js-button">Check/uncheck all</button>

<div class="js-result"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/emmwj458/1/)

Comment: @Greg I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

CheckBox should be handled with onchange event.
Below code I am firing an event whenever the checkbox checked programmatically.

Below code may help you

```
    function setAllCheckboxes(divId, sourceCheckbox) {
    divElement = document.getElementById(divId);
    inputElements = divElement.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) 
$('.checkbox').each(function() {
                this.checked = true;
                 /* this.click(); */              
                 this.fireevent('onChange');
                 /* or you can call this.onChange(); */
            });
{
        if (inputElements[i].type != 'checkbox')
            continue;
        inputElements[i].checked = sourceCheckbox.checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried the code you posted, it doesn't select any checkboxes. Not too flash at javascript sorry.

Comment: Could you post the html code as well for better understanding.

Comment: It's just a bunch of these `<li><input type="checkbox" class="focusable" 
onfocus="parentFocus(event)" onblur="parentBlur(event)" 
value="data to add"><label>Data 1</label></li>` The value of the checkboxes gets sent to a textaera via javascript when the box is selected.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using only java script.
Below is the very simple running example. which consumes short time without any use of external library as JQuery

HTML code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script>
function amend(a)
{
document.getElementById("ta").value += a;
}

function checkAll()
{
var textboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("cb");
for(i=0;i<textboxes.length;i++)
{
textboxes[i].checked=true;
textboxes[i].onchange();
}

}

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="ta">
                Below the outputs
        </textarea>
        <div id="checkdiv">
            <input type="checkbox" onChange="amend(this.value)" value="data to add 1" class="cb">First</input>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange="amend(this.value)" value="data to add 2" class="cb">Second</input>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange="amend(this.value)" value="data to add 3" class="cb">Third</input>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" onChange="checkAll()">Check all</input>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```