# onchange not working when content changed by JS

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onchange

I made a script that selects an option from a dropdown menu. 
The scrips is working but the dropdown menu also have an `onchange` listener, and this listener doesn't fire when the dropdown option is selected with JS?

Example:

If I choose T405 from the dropdown manually the `onchange` script fires.
If I make the my script select T405 from the dropdown the dropdown shows the selected option, but the `onchange` script doesn't fire?

My simple html code (it's gonna be an `img` later):

```
<ul>
  <li onclick="selectItemByValue('bundle-option-132', 700)">Test</li>
</ul>
```

My JS (which is working and selecting an option from the dropdown):

```
<script>
   function selectItemByValue(dropValg, value) {
      var denne = document.getElementById(dropValg);
      denne.value = value;
   }
</script>
```

Is there any way to "update/refresh" the dropdown so that the `onchange` script will fire when an option is chosen by my script?

I've even tried firing the `onchange` script from within my own script?

```
<script>
   function selectItemByValue(dropValg, value) {
      var denne = document.getElementById(dropValg);
      denne.value = value;

      bundle.changeSelection(denne);
   }
</script>
```

----------------- EDIT ----------------

It now works when adding `denne.onchange()` to my script and running this as a "snippet", but it doesn't work on my "Live site"?

It seems that there's an event listener that's overriding the inline `onchange` call? A script called prototype.js? If I delete the `onchange` part of the `<select>` element this script just runs it/adds it anyway.

I'm using a script in my Magento Shop that's called OptionBundle and it's this script that isn't triggered when a change the dropdown option with JS?
If I delete prototype.js my script works perfectly, but it of coarse breaks the functionality of the OptionBundle script.

I'm gonna try writing the author of the script.

Working example (with added  `denne.onchange()`):

```js
function selectItemByValue(dropValg, value) {
  var denne = document.getElementById(dropValg);
  denne.value = value;
  denne.onchange();
  console.log(denne.value);
  console.log(denne);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick="selectItemByValue('bundle-option-132', 700)"> Click to change</li>
</ul>

<select onchange="alert('Content changed')" id="bundle-option-132" name="bundle_option[132]" class="bundle-option-132 bundle-option-select change-container-classname" wtx-context="276DE744-A364-4DD3-AEFC-0D9F9A9AAE19">
  <option value="">Udvælg...</option>
     <option value="875">Bianco</option>
     <option value="695">T400</option>
     <option value="697">T402</option>
     <option value="698">T403</option>
     <option value="699">T404</option>
     <option value="700">T405</option>
     <option value="702">T407</option>
     <option value="703">T408</option>
     <option value="704">T409</option>
     <option value="705">T410</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just trigger the onchange

```js
function selectItemByValue(dropValg, value) {
  var denne = document.getElementById(dropValg);
  denne.value = value;
  denne.onchange();
}
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("sel").onchange = function() {
    console.log(this.value);
  }
  document.getElementById("but").onclick = function() {
    selectItemByValue("sel", 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="sel">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select> <button id="but" value="1">
Click to change to "1"</button>
```

Fo a newer version, try https://stackoverflow.com/a/23612498/295783

Comment: Thanks. Adding `denne.onchange()` solved the problem when running it as a code snippet (sandbox). But sadly it doesn't work on my site as there's another script (event listener) that's overriding the `onchange()`? Added more about this to my original post.