# Appending to reddit <textarea>'s is not reflected. Only appears in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, frontend, reddit

I'm writing a Chrome extension for Hearthstone sub-reddits.

**What's working:** When the user types '[[' into a Reddit comment `<textarea>` it creates a `<select>`. The user chooses a card from the list.

**Goal:** The extension should add the card's name to the `<textarea>` with ']]' so the result is something like [[Dreadsteed]]. This format works with /u/hearthscan-bot.

**Problem:**  The extension DOES add the card's name to the `<textarea>`, however, it is only reflected in the DOM. [The text does not appear in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBElg.jpg).

**Discussion:** I assume there must be some plug-in that Reddit uses that's causing the issue. What I find especially strange is that if you type anything into a comment `<textarea>` you will not see it anywhere in the DOM. How do I get the appended text reflected in the browser?

Comment: My guess, you need to trigger change event after you update the value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually

Comment: You may want to use a different Browser. There might be something wrong with that DOM viewer.

Comment: @PHPglue Interesting, Firefox and Chrome share the same problem but IE and Edge both work intuitively.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, but no luck.

Comment: So maybe you need to share some code.

Comment: Did you clear your cache in Firefox and Chrome? External .js scripts are cached.

Comment: @PHPglue I'm dealing with caching, yes. The code, for the most part, works as expected. It's the discrepancy between the DOM and the browser window that is causing problems.

Comment: @epascarello This is activated on the `select` change:
  $(HearthSearch_activeTextArea).append($(this).val());

Comment: Upon further inspection it seems Reddit isn't the only website with this issue.

Comment: Why are you appending to a text area? You should be setting the value, not appending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your code. You do not use append() to add text to an input/textarea. You set the value.

```
// replaces it
$(HearthSearch_activeTextArea).value($(this).val());

// add to the end
var ta = $(HearthSearch_activeTextArea)
ta.value(ta.value() + $(this).val());

//or another way to do it without the extra varaible
$(HearthSearch_activeTextArea).val(function(i, text) {
  return text + quote;
});
```