# Input text won't change if set programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this input text:

```
<input name="mytbox" id="mytbox"
onchange="Modify(this.value);" type="text" value="Surname Name">
```

When I set the field from an external procedure it doesn't trigger the change event.

```
obj = document.getElementById(id);
obj.value = valore;
```

The value is correctly changed, but not the trigger.
How can I bind an event to trigger in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually)

Comment: please post `Modify()` method too

Answer (score 0):

Call the method Modify after changing the value. Try like this

```
obj = document.getElementById(id);
obj.value = valore;
Modify(obj.value);
```