# A JavaScript exception occurred: Can't find variable: $' error message is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

On using below JavaScript Event code :

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
jsExecutor.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).change();", WebElement);
```

> JavaScript Error:
>
> A JavaScript exception occurred: Can't find variable: $' error message is displayed.

I am not aware of jQuery, could any one let me know how to solve this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you intend to do using $(arguments[0]).change(); ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to trigger the change event by using the below syntax

```
jsExecutor.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).change();", WebElement);
```

The problem is that Selenium Web Driver does not have access to JQuery library. `$('')` is part of JQuery.

Try using pure javascript to trigger the change event.

```
element.onchange();
```

[How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to invoke the function **executeScript()** is as follows :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_of_element"));
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
jsExecutor.executeScript("arguments[0].change();", element);
```