# Call an event from a website - using VBA to Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, vba, ms-access, internet-explorer, ie-automation

I'm using VBA in Microsoft Access for Internet Explorer automation. I've already open the website that I want, but there is an *input* that when typing the text inside, and pressing enter, the website tries to validate the data and fill other fields based on this input.

Looking at the control I found this code:

```
      <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtId" type="text" maxlength="8" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtId\',\'\')', 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;
javascript:return ValidateNumber(event);
       " id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtId" class="TextBox" onfocus="javascript:sObjetoOnFocusCSS(this);
       " onblur="javascript:sObjetoOnBlurCSS(this,'TextBox');" 
        style="font-weight:normal;">
```

I think the `ValidateNumber(event)`is responsible for the Validation of the data inserted in this input to fill other fields in this website.

I tried to do something like `Call document.all(ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtId).fireEvent("ValidateNumber(event)");` but it didn't work.

What can I do or fix to run the `ValidateNumber(event)` function that Validates the data inside `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtId` control?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually

Comment: Is there an URL to share?

Comment: Drop the `Call` keyword.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I dropped, but it didn't work

Comment: At least you're not using VB syntax from the early '90s ;-)

Comment: @QHarr  Unfortunately, I can't share the URL, The url is intranet

Answer (score 1):

Since there is an `onChange` event associated with the element, dispatching the event should execute it. Give this a try after you populate the input field.

```
Dim ie as InternetExplorerMedium
Dim ieEvent
Dim htmldoc as HTMLDocument

Set ie = 'however you're setting IE'
Set htmldoc = ie.document
Set ieEvent = htmldoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")

ieEvent.initEvent "change", False, True
ie.document.all.Item("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtId").dispatchEvent ieEvent
```

Answer (score 0):

The script you mention is associated with an onkeypress event so you could try:

```
htmldoc.querySelector("input[name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtId']").FireEvent "onkeypress"
```