# No space at start of input does not work with a addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I been trying to figure out why this does not work with a event listener. This script prevents white space in the beginning of a input so I need to avoid using

this oninput="validate(this)" and convert this script into using a event listener instead I been trying to figure this out for a while now but no luck here is my code.

```js
function validate(input){
  if(/^\s/.test(input.value))
    input.value = '';
}
```

```html
<input id='noWhiteSpaceAtTheStart' oninput="validate(this)" type='text'/>
```

Comment: are you saying you can't use oninput? It is working?

Comment: It's personal there is a reason why i'm seeking this method instead of that one. Do you know the solution to this ?

Comment: Posted an answer try that, and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `input` event or even `keyup` event. It fires everytime the input's text changes. As far as I know, `input` is supported in IE9+ and other modern browsers, and `keyup` is supported in all browsers.

Example with `input` event:

```
var input = document.getElementById("noWhiteSpaceAtTheStart");
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
    if(/^\s/.test(input.value)) {
        input.value = '';
    }
});
```

Example with `keyup` event, this is a little uglier than the latter solution because the user can see the space being inputted and removed:

```
var input = document.getElementById("test");
input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    if(/^\s/.test(input.value))
       input.value = '';
});
```

Inputs that are changed with JavaScript must be triggered manually, and this can be done easily with jQuery by the following(may **not** work on native JavaScript events, have not tested):

```
var input = $("#input");
input.val("I am going through changes mom");
input.trigger("change");
```

Although, using pure JavaScript to do this is a little more complicated. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually) to help with that if needed

Here is a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/alecdesjardins/pen/RJoWyv) for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Alec I really appreciate your lesson and advice that you have given to us because of you I improved on having a better understanding of this topic today thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Above code works perfectly fine for me. Can you please attach a breakpoint to check is there something going wrong while the function is called.

Few better ways to implement this:
You can use

- javascript addEventListner on this input text to ensure your code works
- Use function like onKeyUp

Comment: He just does not want to use the current way he is doing it. There are no issues if you read comments.

Comment: @Alec I missed on reading comments as It was just now posted a few minutes ago. And yes in older IE version I don't really think this works. So better to use addEvenListener.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<input id='noWhiteSpaceAtTheStart' type='text'/>
```

Javascript:

```
function validate(){
  var val = event.target.value;
  if(/^\s/.test(val))
    event.target.value = '';
}
document.getElementById("noWhiteSpaceAtTheStart").addEventListener("input", validate);
```

Tested on chrome, it works.