# HTML event for setting value in input

Tags: html, django, dom-events

I am searching for the way to trigger some JavaScript when input field is populated by code.

my field looks like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="string" name="total" id="total" {% if object.total != None %} value="{{ object.total }}"{% endif %} oninput="onChange()" required>
```

In this case, if I type anything inside this field the method is triggered, but if I populate context object with content, this method is not called. 
(so the object.total is not empty, and the value is set: value=object.total)

How do I triggered method when value is populated like

```
value=object.total
```

Comment: You might need to add some javascript code to check the value of the input when the page loads and then trigger that function

Comment: so you mean something like : if value <script.../> end if?

Comment: Try `window.addEventListener('load', onChange);` along with some condition to check to ensure that the value is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is by design that DOM changes triggered with code will not be caught by event listeners. However you can dispatch the onchange event yourself. (more info here [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually)).

So what you can do is wrap your logic in a custom function like this:

```
function changeInputValue(input, value) {
  // set the new value on the input first
  // then trigger the input onchange event manually
}
```