# How to trigger event on target's sibling

Tags: javascript, user-interface, frontend, w3c

I have the below mark up and scripts. I have a span with rootnode as id and it's sibling is input checkbox.

my requirement is when i click on the span, input check box onchanange handler should call with the input event object.

pleas find the below code snippet as well as i have give codepen url with the example.

HTML

---

## Checkbox Accesibility Need

```
<div>
  <span id="rootnode" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false">
  <span>i am bike</span>
</span>
<input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" onchange="handleChange()" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

---

```
document.getElementById("rootnode").addEventListener('click',this.handleclick);

function handleChange(e) {
  alert(1)
}

function handleclick(e) {
  alert('event fired..');
// how to call onchange handler handleclick with input event object.
}
```

Example URL : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejKqzy?editors=1010

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create an event in the handler and then dispatch it, like so:

```js
document.getElementById("rootnode").addEventListener("click", this.handleclick);

function handleChange(e) {
  alert(1);
}

function handleclick(e) {
  alert("event fired..");
  if ("createEvent" in document) {
    let evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    document.querySelector("input[name=vehicle1]").dispatchEvent(evt);
  } else element.fireEvent("onchange");
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="rootnode" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false">
  <span>i am bike</span>
  </span>
  <input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" onchange="handleChange()" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
</div>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/lucakiebel/pen/yqEmXP

Answer (score 0):

You should create and dispatch the event manually:

```
var event = document.createEvent('Event');
event.initEvent("change", false, true);
var input = document.getElementsByName("vehicle1")[0];
input.dispatchEvent(event);
```

The documentation for creating an event is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) and for initializing an event [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent).

For further information you can visit a similar post (possible duplicate): [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're trying to do something something that isn't clear in your question/example, and if all you want is to have a label that trigger's the checkbox's event and have it be accessible, then you should use a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element.  There's two ways you can achieve this using just HTML and no JS:

Set the label's `for` attribute to the checkbox's `id`:

```js
function handleChange(opt) {
  alert(opt)
}
```

```html
<label for="vehicle1">i am bike</label>
<input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" onchange="handleChange(1)" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
```

Wrap the checkbox as a child of the label:

```js
function handleChange(opt) {
  alert(opt)
}
```

```html
<label for="vehicle1">i am bike</label>
<input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" onchange="handleChange(1)" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
```

Both solutions are far more standard and accessible.

https://codepen.io/jerred121/pen/dyXrGmB?editors=1010