# javascript function "document.getElementById()" does the work as expected

Tags: javascript

I am working on a browser recording test, in which I am entering a value into an Input field with an 
 auto search trigger functionality.

`document.getElementById('InputFieldWIthSearchFunctionality').value = "Saurav";`

But the search is not triggered if I set the value to the field as above.

Kindly help.

Comment: "change" and "input" events are not fired when an `<input>` field is updated by JavaScript like that. You have to fire the event explicitly.

Comment: And the problem has absolutely nothing to do with the `.getElementById()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Just setting the value will not call the `onchange` and/or `oninput` event listeners of the input field. The auto search trigger is probably listening to this event.

You can dispatch both of these events manually to the input field:

```js
const elem = document.getElementById("InputFieldWIthSearchFunctionality");

// create onchange event
const onchangeEvent = document.createEvent("HTMLElements");
onchangeEvent.initEvent("onchange", false, true);

// create oninput event
const oninputEvent = document.createEvent("HTMLElements");
oninputEvent.initEvent("oninput", false, true);

// dispatch events to the input field
elem.dispatchEvent(onchangeEvent);
elem.dispatchEvent(oninputEvent);
```

This definitely works in Chrome and all browsers using Chromium, I did not test any other browser, that would be up to you.

> Information about manually dispatching events taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856602/7846567

Comment: Onchange() did not help, it does not even recognize the change done to the input field

Comment: @Saurav Okay, I will try something and update my answer if it works

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way... by setting the value directly using JS, you are shortcutting the typical UI that a real user would use thus causing this issue. JS should be used sparingly (almost never) if you are trying to write tests that act like a user would and now you can see why.

In Java you would do this

```
driver.findElement(By.id("InputFieldWIthSearchFunctionality")).sendKeys("Saurav");
```

which would cause the search to fire in your case.