# How to change the value of input so that it triggers onChange event?

Tags: javascript, dom, events, dom-events

I need to change the value of input, but when I change it like `element.value = 'spam'`, onChange event doesn't happen. In the inspector I see that there is onChange event for input element, but when I do `element.onchange()`, I get `TypeError: "element.onchange is not a function"`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

[[Stackoverflow-Post] How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually)

Like said in this post. You can simply fire/trigger this onChange event.

```
element.onchange();
```

or

```
if ("createEvent" in document) {
   var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
   evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
   element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
else
   element.fireEvent("onchange");
```

But if in your case `element.onchange()` does not work, you can try the other examples above.

But can you please add your source code to your question... So we can help you further.

Comment: My script works with a web app and functions for all events of its elements are in the external script. When I needed to trigger onclick event I used element.click() and it worked but here I can change the value of input but can't make the app see it was changed.