# Changing the textarea programmatically, does not raise the oninput event

Tags: javascript, html

Good day
I have changed the data in textarea programmatically, but the event oninput does not occur and I cannot handle the change.
Is there a way  to fire this event in the textarea.

```
let nextElem = document.getElementById('inp_1');
if (nextElem != null) {
  nextElem.value = 'programmInput';
}

<textarea oninput="auto_grow(this)"></textarea>
```

Comment: Events are only triggered by user....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually