# Trigger onchange typing in a textbox

Tags: javascript, onchange

I have a textbox that filters through elements and returns matches in the search as someone types in the box. I want to be able to pass a value in from a different page through javascript into the search box and have the filter execute, however since I am updating the textbox via javascript using textbox.value, it is not recognizing the onchange trigger. How can I trigger that on change through javascript so that it recognizes something new in the text box?

Comment: can you please include an example of your code. It will help us debug it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually)