# Clicking On An Angular JS element with Javascript/Jquery (Tampermonkey)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-events, tampermonkey

I am writing a Tampermonkey script to add more functionality to an existing website and I am trying to click on a button with the following source code:

```
<label _ngcontent-c10="" ngbbuttonlabel="" class="btn btn-agree ng-star-inserted">
      <input _ngcontent-c10="" ngbbutton="" type="radio" value="AGREE" ng-reflect-value="AGREE" name="decision">YES 
</label>
```

The input radio button is hiding behind a parent Label element.

I have tried clicking on the radio button using: `radio_element.click()` (where `radio_element` is that particular button) but that simply changes the state to active. `radio_element.checked = true` does not seem to work either.

Comment: Depending on how the event handlers are bound you most likely need to set the `checked` state of the radio, then trigger a `change` event on it

Comment: What event would I have to pass through the change function?

Comment: As stated by both Rory and Brian, the solution was to dispatch a 'change' event. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually/23612498#23612498