# event listener when selecting an option from select tag dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm selecting an option from select tag in javascript by:

```
let btnH = document.querySelector('#btn_heads')
btnH.querySelector('[value="{{ $btn_heads }}"]').selected = true;
```

and the select tag has `change` listener:

```
btnH.addEventListener('change', s);
```

but it isn't wokring.

you can edit this snippet (I want an alert saying "selected : 7" without selecting it manually):

```js
let i = document.querySelector('#i');

i.querySelector('[value="7"]').selected = true;

i.addEventListener('change', e=>{
  alert('selected : '+e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<select id="i">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So you would need to trigger change event after you set the value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually

Comment: @epascarello Yes!

Comment: @epascarello I tried a lot but I didn't understand

Comment: var event = new Event('change');
i.dispatchEvent(event);

Comment: I did that and everything in that question and other related questions. Can you just try it on the example I provided?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246481/discussion-between-yasir-and-epascarello).