# How do I set the input value in an angular app using browser console or javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I have an angular app with a login modal wherein I take user input such as his/her phone number. I have binded this phone no to `phoneNo` property of the component using `[(ngModel)]=phoneNo`. For a case, I need to interact with this app programmatically and submit the login details by entering the phone number in the input field and then clicking on the submit button.

I have tried setting the value of the input by setting value of the element like

```
document.getElementById('phone').value = 1234567890;
```

This just updates the value that I can see on screen, but not the property of the angular component. Thus, when I click on the submit button, it takes in the default value residing in the component or the value that I enter using graphical interaction on the website, and not the value that I intended.

I have also tried updating the value using `setAttribute("phoneNo", 12345667890)` method, but that also doesn't work. In fact, if I get the names of the attributes using `getAttributeNames` method, I don't see any "value" or "phoneNo" attribute, which makes sense because I haven't written these attributes in HTML code.

Using the querySelector method to select the component and then assign the property also doesn't work. The thing is I am not able to get any access to the actual property of this component that I want to change.

I have also tried using `formgroups` or `formbuilders` in Angular and then setting the value, but then also I don't see any `control` and `setValue` method.

My angular code:

```
        <form #f="ngForm" id="phone-form" [formGroup]="phoneForm">
            <label for="phone">Phone Number *</label>

            <div class="d-flex input-box">
                <div>+91</div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control special"
                    id="phone"
                    name="phone"
                    [(ngModel)]="phoneNo"
                    required
                />
            </div>
       ..............
```

The input field element that I see in browser:

```
<input _ngcontent-vkb-c73="" type="text" id="phone" name="phone" required="" class="form-control special ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I trigger an onchange event manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually)

Comment: @CollinD Tried both solutions mentioned here. Still doesn't work. I only see the change in dom. The component property value still remains the old one.

Comment: You should not use "document" in Angular, you have to send the phoneNo property on submit

Answer (score 0):

You should use ReactiveForm in Angular.  Javascript attribution is not a good way in Angular.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="phoneForm">
      <label for="phone">Phone Number *</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="phone"
        name="phone"
        formControlName="phone"
      />
    </form>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class AppComponent {
  phoneForm = new FormGroup({
    phone: new FormControl('')
  });

  constructor() {
    this.phoneForm.get('phone').patchValue(1234567890);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use the setValue method to set the entire form group to a specific value.

```
this.phoneForm.setValue({
  phone: 1234567890
});
```

I hope this example is clear to you and the problem is solved quickly.