# How do I change the text value in an input field with a default value

Tags: javascript, input-field

I have an input field with a default value of $1. I want to change that value to say $5 and then click a button. I used the following code to try to achieve this:

```
function run() {
  var trade_amount = document.querySelectorAll('.value__val input')[0];
  trade_amount.value="";
  trade_amount.value = '$5';
  trade_amount.blur();

  const call_button = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-call")[0];
  call_button.click();
}
```

The issue is that every time the button is clicked, the $5 or any value I put into the input field changes back to the default $1 before clicking. So, it clicks with the default value rather than the value I changed it to. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: The line `trade_amount.value="";` doesn't do anything here.

Comment: If you only want the first element, why not use `querySelector` instead? Similarly, you can use `querySelector(".btn.btn-call")` instead of `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: you forgot to close your function with a `}`

Comment: How is `run()` invoked, from where, under what circumstances? and show at least some of the relevant HTML. (and I don't see any jquery in your code)

Comment: `call_button.click();` is the part of this that stands out to me; what is that button click for?  Is there any chance it's what's resetting your form back to default values?

Comment: @DanielBeck, I am trying to automate a forex trading site and the button is supposed to be click to enter in a trade. The default trading amount is $1 and I am trying to make it trade $5.

Comment: @ChrisG The missing } is a copy and paste mistake. It is actually included in the original code.

Comment: @DanielBeck The button does not reset the field, it just enters in the trade.

Comment: "a copy and paste mistake. It is actually included in the original code" — well, then edit your question and fix it.

Answer (score -1):

You're probably setting the value back to `"$1"` somewhere else in your code (to fix this, I'd need to know where you're setting that default value). But, if you want a quick hacky workaround, you can try using the `setTimeout` function to set the value after all the other possible setters/event listeners have already executed):

```
function run() {
  var trade_amount = document.querySelectorAll('.value__val input')[0];
  trade_amount.value="";
  setTimeout(() => { trade_amount.value = '$5'; }, 0)
  trade_amount.blur();

  const call_button = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-call")[0];
  call_button.click();
}
```

Comment: The function run() is the only function in the code and so there is there can't be anywhere else in the code that is setting the value back to $1.

Comment: Where do you declare the default value of `$1`?

Comment: I am trying to create a bot for an existing forex trading site and the default trading amount of the site is $1, so I am not the one setting the default amount. I am only trying to change the value to $5 and then click the trade button to enter $5 instead of $1.

Comment: I have tried the solution you provided, unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: So, my guess is that they probably use a framework like React to manage the state of the input box, where React contains the expected value in the input box and only updates it when the `onChange` event is triggered. You might need to manually trigger the `onChange` function after updating the input, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually