# fill input that does not have element id on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, input

i want to autofill input field on page load, yes i am injecting javascript in website,
i have tried xpath method

```
function inputfillclick() {
  var xpath = "//input[@type='password']";
  var inputElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
  if (inputElement) {
    inputElement.value = "KuchBhi";
  } else {
    console.log("Input element not found.");
  }
}
```

it is working but not fully i mean, after filling input i can't click login button, but if i paste or remove one letter and again type then login button enabled, is there any otherway to do that, i have used another extension that is working which is also fill input using xpath, but for some reasons i can't use that extension,

here is element code

```
<input maxlength="140" step="" enterkeyhint="done" autocomplete="off" type="password" class="uni-input-input">
```

you can clearly see in the picture that this method is not filling input fully i mean, placeholder text is still showing,[password problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgSK9.png)

Comment: Maybe firing a "change" event on `inputElement` after having changed its value? Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23612498/4698373).

Comment: any example, how can i do that, if you can provide console script, or complete javascript