# How to mark an input field as changes or edited via javascript?

Tags: javascript, input

I have an user-script that inputs data into an html form. Like

```
document.getElementById('username').value = 'name@gmail.com';
```

But this form has some fancy check to detect whether the field has been changed. So when I fill the field via javascript is gives an error like 'empty value' but when I type or paste the same text into the field it works.

So somehow I need to mark the field as 'changed' or mimic some actual typing into the field to by pass the check, like fake a back-space to remove the last character.

How can this be done?

Comment: could you give some code example of what you're working with? Also what you tried so far?

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually): `let event = new Event('change'); let userName = document.getElementById('username'); userName.value = 'name@gmail.com'; 
userName.dispatchEvent(event);`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common issue, and it happens because when you phisically add some input to the form, an event is triggered (change or input and even the keyup event depending on the action you performed) but, when you use JS to add the value to the input these events are not triggered and the form doesn't know that you have changed the value.

For me, when I found this issue, I created a new event using the dispatchEvent() method.

For instance:

```js
// Get the input (capture)
const inpt = document.getElementById('username');

// Set the value
inpt.value = 'name@gmail.com';

// Create the event
inpt.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

Also, I have found that sometimes separating the "Capture" from the "Set" is better for the code to properly work.

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: I already commented that. If that is the answer, then it is a huge [dupe](https://www.google.com/search?q=trigger+change+event+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Also it is likely more useful to trigger change than input or both

Comment: I tried the dispatchevent but it did not work. The form was smarter then me. However, i found a work aorund using query params which works for me.