# cn.onchange is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, timer

I need to call onChange function and I need to pass parameters in funtion. So  I do this

```
 setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById(input.key)?.onchange({}) } , 200);                       

                        }
```

I obtain this error:

```
 cn.onchange is not a function
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Should it be onChange?

Comment: You might want to fire an event instead like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856513/how-can-i-trigger-an-onchange-event-manually#answer-23612498)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the onchange directly,

```js
const input = { key: 'foo' };

// Assign the handler...
document.getElementById('foo').onchange = (data) => {
  console.log({ data });
};

setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById(input.key).onchange({}); // Call it...
}, 1000);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="foo" />
```