# Calling JQuery Change function inside another javascript function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jquery change function for a dropdown. Tried to call this change function from another plain javascript function. It didnt work. Pls help me.

Code snippets below -

```
/** Plain Javascript function **/
    function selectBrowsers() {
    $('#myDropdown1').ddslick({
    data:ddData1,
    width:150,
    selectText: "Select",
    imagePosition:"left",
    onSelected: function(selectedData){
    var selBrowser =  $('#myDropdown1').find('.dd-select').text();
    $('#selectedBrowser1').val(selBrowser);

   /* This is where I try to call change event - None worked */
    // $('#myDropdown1').change();
    // $("#myDropdown1").change();
    // $('#myDropdown1').trigger("change");
    // $('#myDropdown1').trigger('change');
    //$("#myDropdown1").change(triggerOnChangeForWin);
    //  $('#myDropdown1').change('triggerOnChangeForWin');
    // triggerOnChangeForWin();
    //  document.getElementById('myDropdown1').onchange();
    /***/

    }  
    }); 
    }


/** On Change Event **/

    $('#myDropdown1').change(function() {
    var selBrowser =  $('#myDropdown1').find('.dd-select').text();
    alert("selectedBrowserValue : " + selBrowser );

    });
```

Please note I'm using ddSlick - JQuery Plugin for image dropdown.

Thanks

Comment: see if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/902212/trigger-change-event-of-dropdown

Comment: `$('#myDropdown1').change();` or `$('#myDropdown1').trigger('change');` will do it assuming the change handler was bound correctly in the first place. Is your code that binds the change handler in a document ready handler or in a script block that appears after the dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('#myDropdown1').trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution:

```
function changeFunc(){
    var selBrowser = $('#myDropdown1').find('.dd-select').text();
    alert("selectedBrowserValue : " + selBrowser );
}

$('#myDropdown1').change(changeFunc);

//...
onSelected: function(selectedData){ 
     //do your other stuff
     changeFunc(); //call the onchange function
}
//...
```