# Updating Change Knockout Multiselect value from jQuery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm working on making a few tweaks to a project that uses Knockout, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to update the value of a multiselect from jQuery. I'm sure there's ways to do it natively in Knockout, but it's a tiny change and I really don't want to have to dig into it.

The html for the select box is this:

```
<select id="projectSelect" 
    data-bind="multiSelect: { items: projects, value: filteredProject, header: false, multiple: false }, 
    optionsText: 'name', 
    optionsValue: 'id', 
    optionsCaption: 'All Projects'" 
    style="display: none;">
</select>
```

And defined in Knockout like this:

```
this.filteredProject = ko.observable(null);

this.filteredProject.subscribe(function(projectId)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < self.projects.length; i++)
                if (self.projects[i].id == projectId)
                {
                    self.filteredProjectObject(self.projects[i]);
                    self.selectedProjectCheckboxDisabled(false);
                    return
                }
            self.onlyShowHoursForSelectedProject(false);
            self.selectedProjectCheckboxDisabled(true);
            self.filteredProjectObject(null)
        });
this.filteredProjectObject = ko.observable(null);
```

And my current jQuery is :

```
var projSelect = $("#projectSelect");

projSelect.val(projId).change();
projSelect.multiselect("refresh").change()
```

And that jQuery runs on a button press.

When the jQuery runs, the multiselect updates with the new value, but the code tied to it never runs, and no matter what I do I can't force Knockout to update. Tearing my hair out here, so any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: You could improve chances of getting correct help by boiling your code down even further to an actual repro - answering currently requires some guessing because it's not a full repro, and the code has missing bits (e.g. the `multiselect` binding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout and jQuery don't work well in this manner. You should *really* try to update the ViewModel, and let Knockout update the view. I can nearly guarantee that persisting in your current approach (using jQuery to update the DOM, and getting KnockoutJS to *respond* to that) is bound to be harder and more troublesome in the long run.

However, if you insist, I'd think you need to [use `trigger`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/903976/419956) to notify KnockoutJS via regular DOM events that a different select option was chosen. For your code that would probably be:

```
projSelect.val(projId).trigger('change');
```

To demonstrate how this would work:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ["apple", "orange", "kiwi"];
  self.currentItem = ko.observable(null);
};

var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);

$('#kiwi').on("click", function() {
  $("#sel").val("kiwi").trigger('change'); // Major hack! Try to avoid needing this.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select id="sel" data-bind="options: items, value: currentItem"></select>
<hr />
<button id="kiwi">Set KIWI with jQuery</button>
<hr />
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></pre>
```

Comment: Hmm thanks, couldn't get it to work though. Oh well, guess I'll have to do it native.