# Not able to trigger Knockout data-bind using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

I am writing a plugin using jQuery and knockout. I have two radio buttons. I am using knockout data-bind to check and uncheck the radio button. The problem is that when I am trying to uncheck the radio button on click of another button using jQuery, it is not updating bind observable property .

```
<input  type="radio" data-bind="checked: selectedVal" name="1" value="fixedPrice"/>  Fixed Price
 <input class="hn" type="radio" data-bind="checked: selectedVal" name="1" value="allowBiding"/> Allow Biding
<pre data-bind="text:ko.toJSON($data,null,2)"></pre>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />

 var onClick = function() {
   $('.hn').prop('checked', true);

};

$('#button').click(onClick);

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedVal = ko.observable("fixedPrice");
    self.selectedVal.subscribe(function (val) {
       console.log(val)
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Please find [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhijitm/2n962dno/1/) below with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Welp! Don't mix KO and jQuery in this way. You're *fighting* Knockout, not using it. See [this earlier answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31490654/419956) for a very similar situation and extended explanation.

Note that this is certainly *not* a bug, jQuery will by default *not* trigger events on DOM changes like that. If you *insist* on mixing KO and jQuery this way, be sure to notify others like this:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  isChecked: ko.observable(false),  
  onClick: function() {
    $('.hn').prop('checked', true);
    $('.hn').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

1. The radio button: <input type="radio" class="hn" data-bind="checked: isChecked">
<br>
2. Trigger it with jQuery: <button data-bind="click: onClick">trigger</button>
<hr>
Debug info:<br><textarea data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></textarea>
```

Comment: @Dandy I hope you're only trying it to satisfy curiosity, and not planning to use it. It is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @RoyJ yes i know roy. just out of curiosity.

Comment: Calling `click` on a radio button already changes its value, so you shouldn't change the `checked` value and then call `click`.

Comment: @MichaelBest I thought you were right, but when I tried to remove that I noticed KO doesn't see the actual change. I've updated my answer. If you change my stack snippet and remove the `prop` call then Knockout will *not* update the view model on `trigger`.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery and Knockout are fighting over control of the view. If you're going to use a viewmodel, use the viewmodel and do not manipulate the DOM except through the viewmodel. You have a viewmodel element that controls the radio buttons, you just need to set it. Knockout provides a `click` binding, so you don't need jQuery to attach that, either.

```js
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedVal = ko.observable("fixedPrice");
    self.selectedVal.subscribe(function (val) {
        console.log(val)
    });
    self.setSelected = function () {
        self.selectedVal('allowBiding');
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" data-bind="checked: selectedVal" name="1" value="fixedPrice" />Fixed Price
<input type="radio" data-bind="checked: selectedVal" name="1" value="allowBiding" />Allow Biding
<pre data-bind="text:ko.toJSON($data,null,2)"></pre>

<input type="button" value="Click Me" data-bind="click:setSelected" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug. However, you can try to invoke the native click handler so the observable will be updated.

```
$('.hn').triggerHandler('click');
```

Or

```
$('.hn')[0].click();
```

Here is a [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2n962dno/3/)

Comment: It's not a bug. Knockout responds to the event, as you've noticed, and not to manually changing the `checked` property through JavaScript.

Comment: the '$('.hn')[0].click();' worked perfectly for me. Needed it to run as part of an automated visual regression testing tool that I have set up. Thank you.