# How to get the value to view models when a control's value is changed using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I declare a textbox, dropdown list in knockout js. If I dynamically change the value of the textbox or dropdown using jQuery like this...

```
$('#IdNo').val(_IDNo);//for textbox
$('#IdNo').change();
$('#Subjects option').filter(function () { return $.trim($(this).val()) == parseInt(subjectbind); }).attr('selected', true);//for dropdown
$('#Subjects').change();
```

...then `change()` does not bind the value to the knockout. The changed value does appear in the UI but is not reflected in the View Model for further actions.

Comment: @supercool: i use the subscribe method as I get the dependent values. Problem is when i refresh I get the values changed in the UI as needed but It doesn't get bind to the knockout values.

Comment: it will work fine as expected check here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25697/  . let me know

Comment: @supercool: I can understand the fiddle. Is it possible to retain the changed value when the page is refreshed to the knockout..

Comment: `page refresh` no we cant retain any value until unless we are storing somewhere i.e everything goes back to initial on refresh .

Comment: I store the values in the session. when i refresh i store the session values in variable and assign that to the textbox usnig the above code. When I do like this will it not bind to the knockout? Do i need to refer some other options?

Comment: if you are able to store in session from js you can definitely do it & it should work as how above fiddle works

Comment: I cudn't get the updated vlaue in the view model.. Any suggestion and idea  to resolve this issue.

Comment: As far as I can tell I've answered *the question as you asked it*. If you have a different related question you should probably ask a new one, and *include all the code tor reproduce your scenario* (explain how it's different from this one), otherwise we can't really help you....

Comment: @AarthiRavendiran before assigning check whether you have updated value session variable . you can mark `jeroen` answer and make a separate question what you now looking for .

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make sure Knockout takes note when you manually update the DOM, you need to [use the `trigger` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/903976/419956) like so:

```
$('#Subjects').trigger('change');
```

The `change` method can be used to register *handlers* for the event.

PS. If you're manually updating the DOM, then you should evaluate why / how you're using KnockoutJS...