# Set or change THG (TortoiseHg) branch color

Tags: tortoisehg

Sometimes by accident, or by who knows what, TortoiseHg changes branch colors.

I tried to find in the [documentation](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/workbench.html) how to set branch colors explicitly, but it didn't worked.

I tried an extension named 'color' but don't know how to configure it.

Answer (score 18):

It seems the Workbench settings UI can help with the correct syntax for the config file.

It can be used as documented: `branchname:#HTML_Color`, just need to put it in the correct setting name

What is in the config file at the end is:

```
branchcolors = Stable:#FC951E
```

[image: as seen here], using orange for the Stable branch `Stable:#FC951E`

As documented officially, the value is *SPACE* separated list of branches.

> Spaces and colons in the branch name must be escaped using a backslash (\)

Comment: You forgot to mention "It's **space separated** list of NAME:#RGB", if more than one branch-color have to be defined + some special chars in branch's name must be escaped unicode-codes

Comment: Yes, indeed! It is stated in the documentation though. I will mention it anyway.

Comment: Note that this setting does not take effect immediately.  I needed to restart TortoiseHg.